# Get constructor for local-class in non-static method by reflection

Tags: java, reflection, constructor, local-class

I need `Constructor<TestClass>` instance for local class `TestClass` in my JUnit4 test method.

```java
public void testMethod() throws NoSuchMethodException {
    class TestClass {
    }
    
    Constructor<TestClass> constructor = TestClass.class.getDeclaredConstructor();

    // dos sth in test
}
```

When I'm trying get constructor using `getDeclaredConstructor()` I'm getting the error `NoSuchMethodException()`.

I tried to run the same sideways logic in my IDE scratch and the constructor is found.
The difference is that there `TestClass` is declared in the **STATIC** method.

My question is why this problem occurs and how does it relate to the static / non-static method, and how can I get around this problem in my test method.

---

UPDATE:

I found a workaround by downloading all the constructors (getting a one-item array). But I still do not understand why I cannot get an argumentless (or any other) constructor directly in my case.

```java
public void testMethod() {
    class TestClass {
    }

    Constructor<TestClass>[] constructors = (Constructor<TestClass>[]) TestClass.class.getDeclaredConstructors();

    // constructors[0] <- get needed constructor
}
```

Comment: Because `this` becomes an implicit constructor argument that is visible in Reflection.

Comment: Could you elaborate on your answer?

Comment: You found the constructor (via `TestClass.class.getDeclaredConstructors()[0]`). Now check its parameter types…